# How to parse numeric prefix on string in Open Office Calc?

Tags: openoffice-calc

In Open Office Spreadsheet I have cells with strings like "123kg" "3,45m" "0,5g" "345apples" etc.

Which is the function that can parse the numeric prefix on these numbers? So I get "123" "3,45" "0,5" "345".

The VALUE function expects a 100% correct numeric value without postfixes. It cannot parse the prefix only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to manipulate the data of cell A1:

```
=IF(ISERR(LEFT(A1;SEARCH("[^0-9.,]";A1)-1));A1;LEFT(A1;SEARCH("[^0-9.,]";A1)-1))
```

You might want to keep only `.` or `,` as a separator in the (two) regexps.

What it does is take the first `x` characters of your cell, where `x` is the first non-numeric (or non decimal separator) character. The `IF(ISERR(...))` ensures you still got a number in case you don't have alpha characters at all. You can remove it if all our values have a unit.

You have to have the option checked in "`Tools > Options > OpenOffice.org Calc > Calculate > Enable regular expressions in formulas`".

Comment: Quite hackish but works. I thought there is a standard function to do that. Thanks.